# Change only "Input Date" text of HIghStock Chart without setExtrerems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart which moves from left to right on range selector button click. What I want to do now is just change the date input text on range selector button clicks without any setExtremes. I have hidden the input box because I do not want users to manually type the date. I want the "To" date text to be the max date text of the chart always. Meaning that I do not want to change "To" date text on any button click and only change the "From" date text on the range selector button click.

In the following code, the chart "To" text is (Sep 15, 2017) and when a user clicks any of the range selector buttons e.g. "5y", I want to change the "From" text only not the "To" text. Meaning the text after the click will be "From Sep 15, 2012" and "To Sep 15, 2017".

I know this is something that is not right but I have to do it and have tried a lot without getting anywhere.

Thanks for your time.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aakash_thapa/39eufwm4/2/).

And here is the code.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.RangeSelector.prototype, "clickButton", function(
    proceed,
    i,
    redraw
  ) {
    var rangeSelector = this,
      chart = rangeSelector.chart,
      rangeOptions = rangeSelector.buttonOptions[i],
      baseAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      unionExtremes =
        (chart.scroller && chart.scroller.getUnionExtremes()) || baseAxis || {},
      dataMin = unionExtremes.dataMin,
      dataMax = unionExtremes.dataMax,
      newMin,
      newMax =
        baseAxis &&
        Math.round(Math.min(baseAxis.max, H.pick(dataMax, baseAxis.max))), // #1568
      type = rangeOptions.type,
      baseXAxisOptions,
      range = rangeOptions._range,
      rangeMin,
      minSetting,
      rangeSetting,
      ctx,
      ytdExtremes,
      dataGrouping = rangeOptions.dataGrouping;

    if (dataMin === null || dataMax === null) {
      // chart has no data, base series is removeddebugger;
      return;
    }

    // Set the fixed range before range is altered
    chart.fixedRange = range;

    // Apply dataGrouping associated to button
    if (dataGrouping) {
      this.forcedDataGrouping = true;
      Axis.prototype.setDataGrouping.call(
        baseAxis || {
          chart: this.chart
        },
        dataGrouping,
        false
      );
    }

    // Apply range
    if (type === "month" || type === "year") {
      if (!baseAxis) {
        // This is set to the user options and picked up later when the axis is instantiated
        // so that we know the min and max.
        range = rangeOptions;
      } else {
        ctx = {
          range: rangeOptions,
          max: newMax,
          dataMin: dataMin,
          dataMax: dataMax
        };

        //newMin = baseAxis.minFromRange.call(ctx);
        //if (H.isNumber(ctx.newMax)) {
        //  newMax = ctx.newMax;
        //}

        newMin = dataMin;
        newMax = newMin + range;
      }
      // Fixed times like minutes, hours, days
    } else if (range) {
      //newMin = Math.max(newMax - range, dataMin);
      //newMax = Math.min(newMin + range, dataMax);

      newMin = dataMin;
      newMax = newMin + range;
    } else if (type === "ytd") {
      // On user clicks on the buttons, or a delayed action running from the beforeRender
      // event (below), the baseAxis is defined.
      if (baseAxis) {
        // When "ytd" is the pre-selected button for the initial view, its calculation
        // is delayed and rerun in the beforeRender event (below). When the series
        // are initialized, but before the chart is rendered, we have access to the xData
        // array (#942).
        if (dataMax === undefined) {
          dataMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;
          dataMax = Number.MIN_VALUE;
          each(chart.series, function(series) {
            var xData = series.xData; // reassign it to the last item
            dataMin = Math.min(xData[0], dataMin);
            dataMax = Math.max(xData[xData.length - 1], dataMax);
          });
          redraw = false;
        }
        ytdExtremes = rangeSelector.getYTDExtremes(dataMax, dataMin, H.useUTC);
        newMin = rangeMin = ytdExtremes.min;
        newMax = ytdExtremes.max;

        // "ytd" is pre-selected. We don't yet have access to processed point and extremes data
        // (things like pointStart and pointInterval are missing), so we delay the process (#942)
      } else {
        addEvent(chart, "beforeRender", function() {
          rangeSelector.clickButton(i);
        });
        return;
      }
    } else if (type === "all" && baseAxis) {
      newMin = dataMin;
      newMax = dataMax;
    }
    rangeSelector.setSelected(i);

    // Update the chart
    if (!baseAxis) {
      // Axis not yet instanciated. Temporarily set min and range
      // options and remove them on chart load (#4317).
      baseXAxisOptions = H.splat(chart.options.xAxis)[0];
      rangeSetting = baseXAxisOptions.range;
      baseXAxisOptions.range = range;
      minSetting = baseXAxisOptions.min;
      baseXAxisOptions.min = rangeMin;
      H.addEvent(chart, "load", function resetMinAndRange() {
        baseXAxisOptions.range = rangeSetting;
        baseXAxisOptions.min = minSetting;
      });
    } else {
      // Existing axis object. Set extremes after render time.
      baseAxis.setExtremes(
        newMin,
        newMax,
        H.pick(redraw, 1),
        null, // auto animation
        {
          trigger: "rangeSelectorButton",
          rangeSelectorButton: rangeOptions
        }
      );
    }
  });
})(Highcharts);

var seriesOptions = [],
  seriesCounter = 0,
  names = ["MSFT", "AAPL"];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {
  var end = new Date().getTime();

  Highcharts.stockChart("container", {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 4,
      buttons: [
        {
          type: "year",
          count: 1,
          text: "1y"
        },
        {
          type: "year",
          count: 3,
          text: "3y"
        },
        {
          type: "year",
          count: 5,
          text: "5y"
        },
        {
          type: "all",
          text: "All"
        }
      ]
    },

    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return (this.value > 0 ? " + " : "") + this.value + "%";
        }
      },
      plotLines: [
        {
          value: 0,
          width: 2,
          color: "silver"
        }
      ]
    },

    xAxis: {},

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        compare: "percent",
        showInNavigator: true
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      pointFormat:
        '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
      valueDecimals: 2,
      split: true
    },

    series: seriesOptions
  });
}

$.each(names, function(i, name) {
  $.getJSON(
    "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=" +
      name.toLowerCase() +
      "-c.json&callback=?",
    function(data) {
      seriesOptions[i] = {
        name: name,
        data: data
      };

      // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
      // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
      seriesCounter += 1;

      if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
        createChart();
      }

      var minDate = $(
        ".highcharts-input-group .highcharts-range-input:eq(0)"
      ).text();
      var maxDate = $(
        ".highcharts-input-group .highcharts-range-input:eq(1)"
      ).text();
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to show the maximum date inside 'To' input, why are you wrapping `clickButton` to invert displayed range (from the leftmost to the right)? As for your problem, you can wrap `clickButton` function but only get rid of `setExtremes` call at the end of it and add call `setInputValue` function for both inputs to change values displayed inside inputs, though it does not really make sense.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vefahw8a/